# The difference between 15 and the number multiplied by 2.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

For the following question, can both answers be considered as correct? Is the question ambiguous?

> Write a linear equation for :
>
> When a certain number is added to 3 the result is the difference
> between 15 and the number multiplied by 2.

Answer 1: N + 3 = 15 - 2N

Answer 2: N + 3 = 2(15 - N)

Thank you.

Comment: I would agree that the question is ambiguous.  My initial read was the same as your first answer, but I can't rule out the second.

Comment: Please do not use tags whose meaning you do not know. This is not linear algebra.

Comment: I vote for 1. There are far less ambiguous ways to get 2. I would rephrase and say *twice* the number or *twice the difference between*….

Comment: @TedShifrin My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize. I was just suggesting some unambiguous alternatives ;)